# how to copy a search selection in VI to the clipboard and paste into same file?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, vi

I will give you an example of what I'm trying to do.  Say I have a file with the following data:

```
mv AB12350_PCOUTData.txt ./
mv AB12351_PCOUTData.txt ./
mv AB12352_PCOUTData.txt ./
mv AB12353_PCOUTData.txt ./
mv AB12360_PCOUTData.txt ./
mv AB12374_PCOUTData.txt ./
```

I'm trying to copy just the "AB123xx" portion and paste to the end to get the following:

```
mv AB12350_PCOUTData.txt ./AB12350
```

After which I will append with a ".txt" to shorten the file name.  My thinking was that I could use the search feature with regex characters to highlight the desired piece of text like so:

```
/AB123[567][01234]
```

Then I could simply copy this to the clipboard and paste it at the end of each line and append with ".txt".  Apparently Shift+Ctrl+C doesn't work for searched text, only highlighted text.  I also tried using yank and put with no success.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Or perhaps a better approach to accomplishing the same thing? My actual text files are much longer than the example above so doing it by hand is not really an option.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be fairly easy with a macro.

However, in this particular case you can copy and paste the content using block visual mode (assuming you've actually got vim rather than just plain vi):

1. Position your cursor on the first `A`.
2. Type `C-V` to enter block selection mode (or `C-Q` if you're on Windows and have `C-V` mapped to paste).
3. Use <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> repeatedly to highlight a block over the content you want to copy.
4. Press <kbd>y</kbd> to yank the content. The cursor will return the the first line.
5. Press <kbd>$</kbd> to jump to the end of the first line.
6. Press <kbd>p</kbd> to paste the content.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  My problem was that I didn't know to use 'j' and 'l' to move over and down at a character iteration, thus, highlighting that block of text.  As a workaround I was trying to use a search with regex characters in order to highlight the desired text.

Comment: The right and down arrow keys will probably also work, but j and l are more traditional because you don't have to move your hands away from the touch-typing position.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have access to the directory where the files are
and that you just want to batch operate on them and assume that your solution above was the result of saving the dir listing to a file and appending 'mv ' to the front of the line.

Another approach is just manipulate dir listings 'in-line' and thru pipes.

First

```
ls -1 *PCOUTData.txt | awk '-F_' '{printf("mv %s ./%s\n", $0, $1)}'
mv AB12350_PCOUTData.txt ./AB12350
mv AB12351_PCOUTData.txt ./AB12351
```

when your sure it is working the way you want it, redirect into your favorite shell, i.e.

```
ls -1 *PCOUTData.txt | awk '-F_' '{printf("mv %s ./%s\n", $0, $1)}' | ksh
```

If your filenames contain spaces, you'll have to read up on `find -print0 -prune` as the front-end name generator for your cleanup.

IHTH.

Comment: I added ".txt" to the end of this to append the extension like so:

`ls -1 *PCOUTData.txt | awk '-F_' '{printf("mv %s ./%s\n", $0, $1 ".txt")}'`

After that it worked like a charm and was alot quicker than my original approach, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, on your specific example:

```
:'<,'>s/\(.*\(AB\d\+\)_.*\)/\1\2/
```

Comment: It works, but you forgot to visual select the block before it.